# Series RLC Max Voltage calculation Problem

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, circuit-analysis, inductor

[image]

I am confused on how to calculate frequency for VLmax and VCmax.

Is there a better way to find other than d(VC)/df = 0 and d(VL)/df = 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd solve the transfer function H(s) with the capacitor across the output (as per a 2nd order low pass filter) then move on to solve for L at the output. With C at the output you have: -

[image]

So, if you do a little algebra, \$H(s) = \dfrac{1}{s^2LC+sCR+1}\$

Then put it into the standard format to solve for s: -

\$H(s) = \dfrac{\frac{1}{LC}}{s^2+s\frac{R}{L}+\frac{1}{LC}}\$

Maximum is when s = 0 so using the quadratic solution for s....

\$s = \frac{-R}{2L}+/-\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{4L^2}-\frac{1}{LC}}\$

Now if you know your peaking filters the terms after the +/- are complex conjugate poles aligned with frequencies of: -

+/-  \$j\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}-\frac{R^2}{4L^2}}\$.

It looks like your answer is missing an \$L^2\$ - you just have "L" without it being squared. You also have 2 in front of the L instead of 4: -

[image]

**Thanks to jonk for spotting my error**

Comment: For H(s)'s denominator, \$a=1\$, \$b=\frac{R}{L}\$, and \$c=\frac{1}{L\: C}\$. This results in \$\frac{-\frac{R}{L}\pm \sqrt{\frac{R^2}{L^2}-\frac{4}{L\: C}}}{2}\$ or \$-\frac{R}{2\:L}\pm \sqrt{\frac{R^2}{4\:L^2}-\frac{1}{L\: C}}\$. So I agree with the \$L^2\$ distinction, but disagree with the \$2\$, which I think perhaps should be \$4\$?

Comment: I get lucky once in a while. ;)

Comment: @jonk you do alright buddy!

Comment: @Andyaka my doubt might sound silly. But I am confused why you are not putting s=jw and then trying to calculate max value of magnitude(VL)

Comment: @Andyaka I also doubt this method will work in case of inductor as there will be a square term in numerator

Comment: @NikhilKashyap I always do the "s" thing first then convert to jw at the end if it's convenient. I'm thinking about the square term now.... might be a little while.